# Cannot decompress content stream of PDF specifications

Tags: c#, pdf, compression, deflate

The content stream of the first page of the [PDF Specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) contains the word `stream`, followed by a CR LF, followed by the bytes: `9A FC 2C 16 E1 DB 83 80 92 08 82 AD 7A A1 ...`. The filter is `FlateDecode`. The stream object is at position `0x4312`.

I can't decode it. I get a few bytes of nonsense, and then it throws an exception. I have tried:

- .NET's DeflateStream
- DotNetZip's DeflateStream
- DotNetZip's Zlib Stream
- My LZW decoder (tested elsewhere)
- My DeflateStream (tested elsewhere)
- Skipping the first 2 bytes, as suggested elsewhere

The PDF opens in Acrobat. Acrobat Preflight shows that the content stream begins with 'BT'.

Comment: What's the exception? Also, note that the file is encrypted, as you can see if you open in a text editor and in the 5th last line it contains `/Encrypt 126988 0 R`, that's probably why you get the nonsense. You can read more about encryption in pdf in the same document you posted, in the section 7.6

Comment: Exception using .NET's DeflateStream is `Found invalid data while decoding.` I guess encryption is the answer, thanks.

Comment: Please post as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document is encrypted, as you can see if you open in a text editor and in the 5th last line it contains `/Encrypt 126988 0 R`, that's probably why you get the nonsense. You have to decrypted it first, before you can decompress. You can read more about encryption in pdf in the same document you posted, in the section 7.6

Answer (score 0):

The stream object in specifications says following : 
The contents (data) of string or stream object in some contexts are interpreted as character codes in the PDFDocEncoding or UTF-16 character set.

I used following to get value :

```
            string pattern = "begin=\"(?'begin'[^\"]+)";
            string stream = "stream<?xpacket begin=\"ï»¿\" id=\"W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d\"?>";

            Match match = Regex.Match(stream, pattern);
            string begin = match.Groups["begin"].Value;
            byte[] beginBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(begin);
```

Comment: ??? Have you considered inspecting the document position the OP indicated?